# Display binary data use <img/> tag Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, base64

I have a api to get thumbnail of item. Response of API is binary data of image (I try it in Postman, data is displayed as image).
This is data sample:

```
    ÿØÿàJFIFÿátExifII*>F(iNöÿÿ3Íöÿÿ3Í @ ðÿÛC    !"$"$ÿÛCÿÀð@"ÿÄ 
ÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br    
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ 
ÿÄµw!1AQaq"2B¡±Á    #3RðbrÑ
$4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚâãäåæçèéêòóôõö÷øùúÿÚ?ù(¯ë£Ì

PEPÒ;Q@_Ò5­[H,tÝFæÔ9Ö9GÇMËÑº Õ
+:´¡V."}¨iµª5oµoíFÎ¯Yao)þ¿.üEe\h¯7:V» -ÜÝ9CÏûCúQ@¯Í8,ÆÞT¯J_Ýzà/OºÆÑÄIo©¨ÙëúxÝv·q§÷Ã_ûèV[ÈîrÎÌ}IÍw6×·Vàf`¤`¯U?â«ÞÚé7ùi¬þË1ÿÜ}Ðñùb¿<Í<=Í°ªÇËG÷?Ñ³xÖ¼7'Ö¯ØêÁòIëÈ«w^¸RZÎâ¤ôÎÇÇÐÿBk&âÞ{y<¹á'ëµÔú×ÇB¦7,¯tåN¢õý
ºyU¤ö÷}uw?òÍ¾Wü»þ©8#¸ÊÒ·ÖïãØ²È.#_ádÿß]Zûì£Ä¬]CiëI}Û?ÃÔÂT#-´:
*½¾§at@ÖîNW>Íþ5qãtò°Ê°äê
~q6YÙaê®oåzKî{ü®sÊã©
+ß2Ô
( 4RPÒw Ö§4yõàGsoló²§Þ!qÓók1ÇÑË°³ÅVø`®í¹téºQ]LèbiV(ci$cU$ý+±ðçÖ$½Ô¥±?9µµúEî°+#¸r¦´m¾Mo WQ¹Y>Í!Bä»¹#zc5¯é[éogeâx.Pû·Ô#÷A?~%øÆ7T£Ýë/ÇE÷?S×XtUçy3×~i³Ý¹¨ê+©je¶«7ÁHU6±&¾³Ñ¼8,=MÑÙÀ
üÜ¶ð½¬ÏÆ§¥£·
ïúö|jñwü9o¡É¾­¸Ù³$E^ÊJ@è8Î8í_Æb±söê¹¾í¶Uã²\§×§ÂÚöM}EºkØÙXÛ Hí-ÔÂ5ÿ
øæ/ÚÓV³.ºvÏ;¨djè4OÚïÃý«¢jÖ¯ÿL
L£êICúW74×p²}O¬·QÅ´÷ìPd·ÇüzÁÿ|
ñþÑ?
µi"<I
¼®3¶ê7/±vç^¤x¯HÖ-ïMÔ-®íß;eUèAÁ¥íVÉîtÁi!;­ çþ­ak>°C}comk~|ÕJÉÓ£1ýà3´ÕÕ½FåSz
IÎýFGøÃá×<qm3jNÖ¢b½©ò\ó»+ =C0>à@ùßâÁ»¯y×zMø¼µÀ, H=CÏJúcâ¡q [éñE#ÛK¨¥r-¹a»sºS%Ãa±ópw|çÄ««øè]j«
µEwýù
®W§Êtäq^®UÅ9M4ðµ_/ò½bþ]=U»ÂÂº÷×Ï©ò¨ëIE! WõuóWBþ4P7¬
BppAZ|ìO´qiM ¢¤°¢^´QEQGj(¢*O5~\e9Ù"_ÈÔtW.+ÆCÙâ ¦»4æTdã³)ÝéV7(Õûùþÿ#Y%äy1l¸_úfyü?k~ø¬ÇÃ¬«wBôºûèÑ´q[«É$FG^¡«z~©yeòÅ)1ÌmÊÀ×JäH¡&DdPÀ}3Óð¨aðìZ¤ÂßM²¹7L  XàÌeÓÀxÅ~pgÆUiµ8G[§ÊÒ]Z£fð­;-Èmu[[*Àç¨×üjé_8ee=9¬CÃÚ­ÌöòZL&Ù%¬±°8*Èy£µf?(ûÔªxý+<·3¡ªU½øöw·ßïºì9Ò·G_1å.27¸aÞªÉ«iq)ÃÍpÝcj©<þËÑF?Äçí   ªk´Wêîþë    Rèo'ÌsnMµd!egcùéV Ö,®ïFµcØÉùõã\Íãaø£7ÃÖöÑÄI¿7u÷;¯òè_,ZµÌ©ÚÊz09èk¨øU®YøÇZ~¡©xn°  ýÛ¡Rp:ã9Çµy]¥ÔöÏº'#Ôv5±o®BäLgûÉÈü«ï°üyÍpÀæÐpSVr«ÖÛ«ÛÆJ ö>£¾ñÃè  <G
@ë´Æmçzd%s0ü2²kzrû±èI^Wà%|SâK-ÖéPÜ¾IÚÉ8ü+Øïgô²1ÊúüóÅüJ¶aIöÎóÊ¾+9Ë8?)©uqÒnKrÇMVéY=6;Þ?jtôÛ{~fIð÷îÔ¢xB@xùõÓô$Vm×¼=(Óõ+RØ*[Øj0¼²@±¾ìzÀ$    ®öÇáö`¶¡hmsm2ÞZÍs¿Ý£ydýTwñê:CÿÈ¥ 2íÁ¸Ó´»kyA=H2¸Ãí_b³\«ØG6¿¼ýSÚ¥âä½û/Çò<£Æ¾±³`3\1ReXØ^õÈè8«O
"]1IEO­zµÖ£üJ¢
6íW²HsÔul¸ô¯Nø1¨ÅáÈ$xN¶¹Ú±VîñüË -1¼¨Æ@,A5ÑO4ÃÉZö}çÖÈq±æO¬Vç'    ­|¯#Ê°PmËøW5skâ
ê¯¶-SG¿a    P^¯±t¾¤l<O§ÿdJd+¼Lf'ðÈXªåX÷PÛmn|uðü-Õi«h%ÁFsÞ2xù[ëpyÆ+¢5ã5uª8k`kaæ£R./Ìù·áçÆ?éºqÝæ bl'eKeYNz±}ûþ.é÷ºl7z5R.EÈùí{÷ÂÈýàCÒ¾q]Ñ4íBéó-¤¬Ýí)Ã¦Æí»JòqÔA¬øenlõ«Ï¦¤Ù^Ùä}®£$ÐeÉ<e­MZV4éÔæ%EþgÐÞ6ñß¯4ilÿ´í.å6,1¿ò×¹-Áì+ðg4Í
:}IúöwóT¡Ó©#HÀõ©>|%½Ô[íBYc´$X{£ÐûúóÕúô<KákHm/4Ií!ûMË¶ 9¾hÁ_âM¿!©a(_sxÊ1V<ÏÁ?~#xÂÏMÔ4JÚv¢Ì!½TXVÚÌÜå@9ê2pv^óðÇöI¶O.ûÇºÄ°|ýÄíRqºB3;Ï\×¹ø#VÐ´=JðÎx¾]¢­¸òÌ@÷?äWqÛËu¯ÖóÎ?Íê¹S¥jQmÙ¥ï5wm]í¥¯kj|Õ,-;]êys~Ï  ü~h½o&ÈãÝyO?e%ÄÞ¾¶¸·å£äýÜ´~+êº+æð\[`çÏòüBkeØz¿fÏºÐüÃñ×õÿ    \´zsj2@ó# uÁè
åAÈâ¿A?k­MKá4÷0ÛMé4¹SIüÈ¯ÏÉY]G@Æ¿sá\úYæëRNÎÇ#:5];­Ó
J;Q_Ft QGj(£­QGJQ@  E:×¢ü.³øsáíNßÅ?h]sÎSd~ÑåDcÇ#wMÛ|ñÓ½yÑ¢¼üÏ<vTaVTÛûQvjß§rá%]«®xÃ6JnSÔÒ"¹Áé»#"«i÷:V¡KõP¹ù&ºÛs*Ê ¿ï}xèEoxbÚßE}_^91·¶øW¨cî{ÇÒ¹ß£ùs%¥¤¹RbO,øê}Ï?Zü?Ì±®´ðrÅºÔâ÷Ù;yk{?6¯ªî{xzp²-§ªøoWk¶ç·ºy¿xÎ$(I?õÐ)5R}ZXÏÚ4áuáf~Ålxgâ]±±N×ô8/íB4eV¨®y¼1½Þ+ØHèD®îáNNr1]«±U(G£N¤ôzyY¤½R#êp¿2m\ò+ýMÍ§ËÆBåß*ÜÏð¬þ4ßí{ù,?à$úW°j6PHÚQ.bgæ±ßkÇü93G%«yl¸Ñd%²}6ãÓÈÅyG
×êóá¦û^¤þÜ½/eçÓ³    bñúºR·K¤ÿe*ÅXGÔëß±G§ë"ù:tó^#R¡¾n8q^wâßëÕ?³uû³¹($U,]OFVRC¡¯öô%7SRZÛ¥íÖÏS<vUÀÊÕà×â¾õtcÔ¶óÝÝEkkO3ã5,ÎÄàRME^ýûé%¥ª|DñÆ]!á³Òa=Â[ÙÉÇ©Fqá¸ÛÕU(9¾.«ÔPSèÙãáñðt¿ê¶°Á«¼2]Ýl!rÃ{u­jH(*cçyâ¹SñK?ØN¦y¥ux4vÙrB¡ãäõ_ã]Ä[Új¶òcY7FÆñ×ðµÕ:ïâ½ýYú&R^I|)+/³¤xÊGaucÄüß/#ñ5«­\øWÄ,ß`x­ïöåaÝôì~W^\G£x\ÞZëv¶ÒV8ôûKÈ[kFðÄæQ°®FpWeUº»½ì×Ö×é·³"YM   Vó$`§ÊÚ¬ÌßêÛæÀ?{êõarÝzìõ*§òË×óE¸4Í.ßÅÐÅ©£Æ[+.ôp»G,¤s÷¹ÆCv½ßßB¸´·»µ¹$8"ßÍB¯/ø­Zêú<qH­r¾z²pHìÙß8ôË<7a«øÒ-+I³m?MU>uË.Ýã¹çIc×=òk'O
¤ßôºÚ)ò­:ÿ_æp~ þÒ×|@ºl5ÔÈa*&v;FqÜñ_pxoÄ0¾ö}Mn-Ë7Ïnñ§<YÆ3ñÿ7p-Ü¶È±$Ò¥!\¿Ëo©Ýï3A[¾33|ðÝjÐ¦mï¤DÛÝ=Ár£æ9Ú µÝÍ¦ª**)z6oúÓudÛkôÿ>røé¥ÿcøËYÓ/0\@Ìù*¨`ýÒ{ÔÖ¯x?T¸wE½Fbo+x|«~RÕ½ãm*Ú]^;½Væ}JÖ0^7QºpvÉT*#·ÞzáxG+Éu{­ÈÒecè~¿çÀúºÄ¥   ßæ{î¯ñïCÒàt·¶¹)Ú®6×Xô`ô¯/Ô~+èú÷SPºyì|Õ6óy±ü¥pY+Ã8ÀÍq'oçgDTWÑìqüû~`ñ¢o0¶Cã8þZ¿bSkT¤~xxö´ÜH$¼y#'îPqÓ'ú×ÚèT)Î=ëåÿ~ÏÚÇ×UÐ+{/4¸dÁç®:WÐ¾
²¿±ÒRMüËçß»wè+ïø¿ÆF|$ÖKª<Ú)Å´Ñ¹EWÃ~ÓZgÁÍ#Ò[ggp¼~Â¿7ÉÃ±n¹¯ÕxoFñf6¯Y» Ê".Ë¤ÊG#±¯µÙ(Þxúy,5htÿR¦ºÆÑ¸@_½ <pzWêÜÄ¹fW«C'ß5í£VJÊÚßÊÇ¥QÔR¿CäÂ9¯ºtïÙSáå½£Cuw«]³JÌ.v÷x^þ¿:×Ê<
oàÚ¿l&kkGC¹ËdWÀØ¯Ðòn*Ë3D°øVù¾ª×Z/Ôç¨êQJUçÅúö¥¯¢³±¢|ÊáERQEP)G¥(+Ñ¾xsNÕõ=gXÕQf´Ð¬
áù¯½UGÐdÂ¼çµwµoÚXFXÛêa­.cT20Îxô ùþ*gâ=­%ïäµßÑ¶ÞÕ\_xïQkÉe¸7@6Û+È\pyÇµæúÃ\¹Þ5ì^>Ð|É§¶µÖÞXee6C¾ñà*ò½GK¹GKNA¯æõ©ôQµ"be^5«á«F9v#ÿ,ÈÿëU¢±êóYÛEaohÐÆ"XC(`I½HÀ>ØhØÆ¶I9üÌûT`z×' Æ3®ªÂ9¦ö:p*ºÊvÂ¼G1Ï«eÎIì1Vu[i4xwJÜLÁÙ    û§hqÇóÖ½sÀ>²ûÚ®°ZªáÖkfÀþòç#¯¥yÿÅ©¬nÅ¡,³ÁTl<~]É¯xXÅZ'Üäù40.¥Jæ]/eÕ¯6ÎgFÕ&hãºÊq×=;Ö¿ìï<wàÛ+¨·º\èNýRtöB/cÄÓ4Éà±Õ/·ú~'Âº\oUl4i4è¤ÂÄ¾bÆù9!Fî@çOñÏÝ©Ý^}l?ÖðþËÞ×³þ¶étyî·ð{âFÉ/îo#aÚtÞ=ü}¿)>xª]þÆÃSi"ÓtéîïÌ<ó½¸:gäqÆã_EYø²Õ,Q¦Û¸¨8'¥dë÷^ñM«Ù@þZàKsò2¯û2=²+¢Y­
Ñö<Oõ2¦j¶¦«]Vkº9û­zÖßÄÐk$¼·Y¢¯<¼ePðAÎ×V\^«á?    x×Æ_·i7öz¤IimfdAµÙ7's±m$¯/øxéú/ìï¼âe¸   cí5H¤0üÜ.Ð6·HÍ}×á^¿ÓìL¾µÑ!çkYãXî7)òÃ9Àb}¹¥GGÓ¨ûZú;zngÇSkÒéµiFþªÿäÞø#©k±´ÕEÿo´ýB[ü¿Ü-î#*êåAÞy|®GÊB¶Å{þµá-WÌ¾±ÔÂbdT»çWV,íÊË '®ÔÓõ-B$Ææ;¨$]É4'|l=p:µ^Ý*1§MSZ£ä18ºë:²Ñù1ücøHm<Wq®ØÚK-ÎæI_Þä!KB¿0ç2ðEfxôïDou6Ï¶ÃgH|¹AÎæù¾xÇOöKÞéñY»·¬á»kHÅ»J$U?w)Æã×ß>ø·Äë~³µ¾óXë!ÌûÍÏ3ëÓt+ä³GBOg»_-oÀûLx¬L#:/Ç±Éü3½ßXñ9æt¹´dlçz[±ÿÇÍiøéeUîÙánÐî­£l5Ê8*9fby|ó×á  Y.õv    4ÊgÚ8,êïÿ¡þØëÚ§iªé¦[ï¬Ï!@à,hvqyr±5È¨)ã)®ú?EoëÔöq5],5J³?øÀâü]e¨ÛØ\Iy y£MB#XÀ,Á¹÷¦ªO"°,[ =ijúì)¿[­M#···ÓÍÕOo·CÀäíÇÕ,Ò3;LxÝõé_yF?Çåµg)ü[7#©®#_Ï´ÝL`c¦OþÍ]F³z U*G<í\gmVÎÈ!;ù÷þf~´Ðhª:¥
,ó¤vÏëW¹;"Ká®A§U-.cyoÉÞ¹tUÜQ(ò»QE å~4øàÿøû_×eÔ$¹º@`] ôäA^©EuàñøÝL4ÜdÕ®·±JPª­5só'ã7¤ðÄMKÃMp·1ÂCÃ(þ(Øesï½qýëéïÛûJµ·ñ'5K{#·L3¬$,Øã±»äWÌ5ý-ÃÙó,²&¾«Fþv¹Àà©ÉÅIKõ£W²QKI@z(ïEÐ|;×<g¦ëoÈòåÔåH*}{çè®|^º¡Sáiú5b£'èzoÝîMåßj9Y!³Ï>ôÍ7ÁwÞ ÐÎ¿p²w¼6ðÃoéeuUf;:°Ãõ;Ë2ù¼óMº6Wö÷[A«!FÁÎ<W°ø«ÀúôÚ'ö÷ïçÃWî·KÑ.6H"ÙóíÁüéÆ<?['=9ÞÒµ¬×FµéÖúë¡õ¹5:Yqså¶ªòwßärwøWDÕM¥Ø¨d>d
«!°+0ã#§ÏNµ×ø[Æ~Í;ÀÝí¥ ýó\lÕ­Òæo³Ü¼¿Ç4ûN8äõLÖ
ÂÜI+åâC¶=¸lÔ    Ï§züÖ¬Õy.i7¯sôZç¤ý#Õ´NþJ÷»=7âÆu­
´oèÒC#%¿»#ÍÚ1òÇª:Äç¢×¡j:T³ªÞÝOe+|®Ò¼FO¯S·ò¦Úøi.,åäd³.Uq¬Tþ Ömö}lÇÍ¶)ýõþcûÜ
ÉjáA¥º©iëÞ÷R^Z[¦­·ðk5Ì0øR×ùe¬~]¾G¨øbÏO¹Oo®iLªÅpoQ}Hb1q©Æ9ëVoâg»ó`¶ýÔsD¹Bù<gØW,ÉBTÿrNü
CåÈIÂ1Ç=+ë²O8oåQbÝDÕÒ2ïÿ­êV/ó>Enì¯s¶þÙµKuo¹@¿\þ@Õ"ës,7WÒFIÊ @ÏÇÞ¹EfG¬UB1WíµGGV$Ä>Vüú~b?Â`äêåÒçò£Ò/ð91\]ÇAR®ùcÙlýz(ð>¡ ßcmöµQ¸<°Ç·­P}{ZÓ#X!Ìò¹!$0Ç®:Ï4ºWo,n¼ëk«»'þüÇ¾9?vðøÃLñ#þ}2-FO»öëFX.O½*ø÷õ¯ÌòZøv£¢ãÚé¯¹õù1àsJøVå¯½¿ÈÐý>,|PÒîõ=;MeÔ¬¬¬ôé·(xÕcæP7    É=Í{ßi
?Yìn<=¤ê75|Ø#\à¾WÝTäàÁÈùÿA°]R+ÿ
j9MâtÁ¯¦jõnô¹
¾·c+ìPæÂÊO?}    
F6ËÁ'y5áã(Wæ¡·cÐËÿ³qRåÆ¦þ%úÿô|M¡4ïí§-±,v3¶àÙP¨kÈ> èþ ´Ñ´9®t­RÚ{+¨Ì¬%À]® .9é×½3Ã¿4É®RÒ;·0"l'Øv'Ø½¯ê¬¥6X)+¼¥±òG@Nzäà_/Rö¨7õä}¾,)¹Pª5®ïO4ÿCÖ/íýlÂAk¨mä`-²2ê3?tÚ¦cþÊº`/DÌÂ8F    SÁÃFækâ¸µ·ö~ým!c>yRÀÿ¬vÀ0
«ÀÂsê×]ÌH+Ód«®qwdØÃFxJMÞÝ½43Ãºxªð^ëmj­êûêp¾*¼³øM
ÊÎ
gpÕ²gAÁÀÈÁÀé^iâ¿êBwvÅzw Hüfæó¿´®ÕnpvÆò±C¤ò@=W_éÿÚ7Ýmñ)} ùT·¦[§§×µöXzþÒ?-Æa}ySÔ]*ê}^ö6¼%Jà   p   ÷ÅfKrouæ»-$ûÙSÎk¢ÂºÕ»½²Ãm¦C"ãÊºÔàFÇÌ¹ü«´øðnnmnõ-VÖxÃ*Y>ñ ôßÀðpÔUJ´#«fk
Q«Xýðî§¥nÆ!"ùrG_¡ïQx²ÚÚ}1ÖâSß=«ø¤jZwÖ×R$Bp¿­zt±¤    Fzf½|m8a1mSÒÙQnQÔ¯¤Ê²ØFË»8ÁÝ×5i($MHÒ6bw\Snbó"`£$\WiÊå­ê¶â8©|üôïTá´h¤P\Ñ±ëZ@``UÍElFh¢Èý£¼â:|Ð­-,,ôû¿´M¨ê9A+ÀHBb>sBTM|OñÁç|Wqá¿B©uGC6û®§¸<þ Õú_?¶&±{ªüwÕ »X4Ø¡´'?»Ùæd\ÈßN«õß
óMZÏ/I*Qîµ¿[ßÐâÄS·¿}O éI@¢¿]1z(¢ÑÖZJ(¢
ÐÐõ½cCº[­T½ÓçV$¶£9A¬ú+:¡V.iôz¡¦Ö¨Ü×|]âmqÑõmrúñ·©RpßÞúû×KáO×Zt?b×t»}^ÑÜêD+çAäçæV>â¼úñ1¼/ãhû
Øh8ùE+z5f¾Gn3Æaª{JUZ~§¥ÝjZ]ÅËßøO\?¼9MÕ`u;rÅ[q1'îñwâ±¦«¢]iÛ¿å¦Óµ½Æ@®®iúåæÞfØß?$áB8¯Ì<1 Þ_VÖÚ2×åÌµKÕ3±f¾Ú§>!j÷kó¶ß;áñ­Æ÷zcÃy  !H,¸î×½gÛi:æ1¾ÑïeÓîBdÀqÔ©Ôàd
2þçÂÅÉ!½Ò/1¬q   ¢Ù·ØÇrk?FÕµ+e2Ã¨Âß.B{®¨5ùÕ|4Ã©Gm¾þ®¿Ñ©*
ªKîkÕàÐüQnÏ­øMMBÔ¬S¤pÏÝ`¯9Úµ|Y¡[é°Áá4}"â&`ZK4¶áT¸m¬9ÇóÔ
òÖ$¢\é÷/Áur¸Èë\õþ±¬ÄY`Öo&±>TÒ\úàÿ:ùº³xÒÄK¤[v·mícé(æÙt©F8¬2rë$oÏ¦½õ=ÃÂÚÏí}å¨Ë$c±¶YÜïa¼O@qÅ¶i£möÚ4ß{ìë$¦âbO
Ñ%8ÛO|cø¯ÞXjQêV0u¤BÇG)àLöÆk«ð®§núâßM«Í©j:Ü¼rmi  ¶u=sÏ~*xÌ\%ì¥ZQÑÙ´­×KÚÇ©t!up¸xÍÆ-Å5w'Ñ-.ßÉ&ð«c¡Jît¶_Ëà1rÅ2ä`c=s¢|E$ú?öuì)pD2¸ù×dïtéí^­wðóZÖ´¥¾%îªvc¶Ðrÿ<÷ÆZ¡¦FâûL@îtv~Rs»iôéU,ê$©Á7æÞ¬ð²ÞÅâªã1SbH¾Ü×ùu×fÎ_UðÌZ¦ý£hÉ*'Ë0Fýä'±eôô#4ïøªïG»M+ÄÕþXîÉÈ¾oÏ®E/¶Í¤]Ûj.î3ä{ ã>üÔ·ðÅâ[[Æò¢ÕLc\a×·~>£ô'N>«üÑø¼î¿^Í_3¥ñ­­µÕ¼¦õÉuksà­ßÚ¤s/¹Â¨oý¼Ï]¼m#ûyZFt=Ó§å^ð}ÓPµ}Íûè'xÁ1bÆ¾G1Ãº4¥ ïý3ï%SÆÓè+'«ò{?¸îüIá+¯
ßO{qqYdA3ã9;XÂY9'å`Ääà<+VfîH¨X1üOCü¾µî^'KËïxÂïdí01Æ£ì}  ~~{WË
ãµ}X¯¯º_ùvs'Tãæÿ3T¶ìÞZqÐ¢Ç;qøóRøÅþñ½ýEÄ%¾YÜdàöÏ¡ Ü»meeÈ#¹Å¶X/L|I?Ä¤ö÷ç¥wÊ)«=23iÝnÕ÷lx\ñÏÖ¸%×ü=g&¯o§h-ÎOý3^²¯lp}j¸a½­Fxaí]ØJÐ£QJ¤9Uäa$ÚÑÃ¯øÃÄÛÞê0±R¤gó¯G¦ApF±ÄFS¯N½G*pP]E4µceBëÅNsJ¹Ô´W)AE®×KGTÇµ\!Ìí{   »w0¥Å¼J3Q¨#¾ý¯¾ø{Á~7ÓÂÍå¥ý©âÈÊò¼N­0³±8|ôìPú×Ýk   ½TÕ-KÃz¥«Úêúeuh
ÛÜKi#<{rx÷¯¢áþy3Û;Êwz=4¿£ëºükÒu#e£?,n-î-¥ÄL;0Æ)÷×íáxu¿·zv1Kw¤ÌK'GHþìã    ð"ô¯Þ8o>§`&0äiÙ«ßô]û2¥>Fî-P+Ý,h£ñ ( 1E
;Q@¢(¢SHl2<©í^¿ðÛàLþ Ñ´ÏkÜÙéSÆÒJ{*{)ÈÉÇr<¾ÐÒüqaª|ð¥Ä¨1éÑYÊ¨%Ã¹\ý¯Åüc§O  ÓÆS¦åÊä½4OÍô{«h}
ÓxZ¢õ[ØòZv¢ÚÁ¡x{Kµ±·fFEùßø,Ç%º÷$Öïì½ðïIÕ5ësU8¶²d.T
Û¼0¬2za9o:ûØ¥W\´ và?µ½ðÓÄ7zvÐÚ°@òuè\qÏùö¯ç.*t¨{Iëw÷«âðn¥J>ë]{+t>ø¯Y¤oªcC`ý+Ã¼_¨G}5ÌsH~ÄÈÑºï*
äïÍgk>&»»Eyp¹+×ó®7WÕÔÛËr@   F26ç¡$Øg8ÈÏêÕÆ×æµ¿Aà²Ø`¨¨§Ôà¼FoÛ)Î³±fãèqíPiZÅ´÷s;o"%?â+¥ðÞ5
jÚ$jùÇF`Ãô)\¡Ñ5´SðdwG¿©A_ybéÆ2åk~§ÌgYf"¬áVVÑ_gÔE¶ûV°°¢Ò!Rà}Áwg×ãßõ?
§ÙõÛ9QÇåK0)ÅrÞÒ£]¸-$Ü+²ã*;8Éú>¹î4+s46·(ÜE;}FÜùãò¯ÍñqÄ×ËCÙË0ÃaT'¿ü{ÄvfK=ZG¬réhÂ1 E>_$w'øPKã¿+ËÚÓm¬N«¨'ë^½Ç6·g±´6w0I.Ag08È=FÑúóXcòÅÝþÏ,sbPîJ×µÔo  ¿?Ìø~$§Ëåÿs÷°þç8Åsú´F3Ê ,¬ç¸'üþµÙj1®ÆÅsÓªÈ2:üëÛ>};;zê-ÏNú;gY?(9vç8ü+¬²Ö]M-!(Ï$~aÇô¯0ñ/Âd7:Î}2L¸ÂgÀäòO5 iþ"ÒüDoæ½s"§7£xÀÅ}|²ü&t*+¥³VÔäöÕôo-D?21Py
êv²Ú)Ö@
zZñëËùîi[îtÞUÂn|õèrâº
/_Ð­m$KY ­ZMÍÂ³tÉê{×S'pjíùFµÙéªC(aÐÒ+Â:¡ÔìEÄ·rNÅì;c>Õ¼FF+Æ«MÒ·F©Ý\ÏÖµ{M&Í®nd@$òØì=êâ{;õËÚÞZ·Y¢+Æ´n´»¢âaÊîç`[@?å­¨(Y¦ßqkrD`Êt#"ð3H¨»T`zVo­µÏ
jVºUÁ·¿ÚD¶l©ÚsÛÊRvO©GÍ¶¯ÅhbÒÃÿêå³ª´G¤C¤Y÷=G ÇBE|W­?u¯\Au \2ÜÝL¡9ËoÉÜ>ê+KâWìÝãOhëFîÃR±µKs$$©C uÏWô.EÉ²\=<<D\¥­î½æý>å~ã)¾f4PEöFAA5¡á½"ï_ñ¡Ø7zÔvÐ8ÝÃ&¾²°ý´ìÛQ{âË¯·å¢·=Øä $Üõöíâæ¼CeqårÙ$ßä>IÉ{¨ø÷9£<W´~Ñ?åøaem«Yßí6â$3:6Üò=ð/ÏÅÁ®ì?
áÖ'.h2SiÚJÌ(¢ì
(éF(G­%PEP_Aüø{â]SáÆ¾·Ð[iÞ&¶Ì.¤îSvÕ<$M|ÿ\Î[Å$Ò¹Â"),ÇÐ_£_úºB]iBÞâ=< ´6*þö9ú×æ(ÕòSSõV×Oëk÷=³SzoT|Óâ¯ZiÑÔ/'RM¢dh< ²»I'hÉï¤&á[[H£S|¤ôÿëqÏ5ªºô¾"Õg/<·~\ÿbYääÎÑ(¿à@Iêêj;É^ÖòÅ#3/qB3ÿ¾Æ¿«>J    Y#ú/Q2æm+üÿBß$ðöÒ¥üFPÂÚ¯îËÉ*Tû­9ô®)ô»^âèÇoå"Èî{qT¼eeªx£Ä³êNÐExó"U
«Ø¨9Òj÷2Ål²Âa2ÆÕ;Xí gä7Ôg#"º+FqTwßKYe:ÎzMYè¯{ýæ¥{iá1¬Ó2^ÍóIcv;{õÏjã-î¯õFÐÜ<\ò®ËxW¹ä±ëÓ'éMñ$'k13Mwts<Ì:/§ÓÓ>ÕÑü(]øë|JU¬]`$r¬%$ÀIúÕÉ*4]K]Úç&'å?dÝío?>ö_#©Õ¡X-,ãHÂÀµáá}Ö y,\¨õQ*ò"þtßA}µÉ`!7%»m^§ô5wáöRi³²¸±ÑD#)%
HAîú©¯  EÊo¦¿wüÖÄ(òÛ«·ãÿ`ø{Q_]¶Á5ïÙíã=HÑÙÛñ%áX+xm<M¨Z!Û¶áãÕÿxV5½ám>[½KÃúàa¾¿ó8ìÉ*©?Pó®3Ç÷¼m©H
*àúá1_cC(ùùþ{SÚNRó!Ô.2ì õàÖDX7*§¦áO2$æªK(2çõÏJçêEGå}+ñîgk¡O{?¼Aøc½uÕÝ¼WP4(dn¢·Ã×tj)t¹2±ò5èµ=|¾ ][É@.LË=ÇÅz¼!}¯5¼÷-®Ës¸¾;Zõ]cÀúTÖF+;#gl¥FGã\obñüLt9PK§D¬ù.   èyõÎq_u<î+ÖrÊ+«»kær{.Y{Ç¦øzÀÙéñÅ2F]GP&´÷.í¹ô¬ëã%½¸»nÜv9ÅK¦+´fiAó    ï_Ró½FÎÅ¦Ú(¢°QE`g8æ¨ëÖVú¦w¦]©k{¸^T1RÊÀ29¢¯R2«.âªqÝùñ_Àz×ÃïË£ëêó%´±d<ðC`dúð+úWß´ïÂ­âoö
¶tÛx-'f¸w"@à?(×$ÇÐÛüøY#ÑÂvr¢FÝ:ÿ¤¹îÆQÉ>ôWí¸op°4gNU%~ev»»ëºG# Ûv>øcqygñÃ×¶]ÜÛêPKýédS´}qýBBJAàö®;À¿ü  àÚçÃ¶´¹eÚgbÒI@ÌIvUðaÄ3ÚôçF* «½ÝüÖõ6¥MÁj|çûrx²ËLðU¤ÓîëSf9]¸¶¸äî WÄµú=ûIxa¼SðZ±µÒWQÔ!%¢C"8`IRÝÎ9#sùSàìÿªøãP{ï%æ¢@qY®O<&Fì~Hû®ÎòüG9Ö|¼|ÚÝ¶ö²ü-äßsÐf÷Ú£àöðÊ]&ûÃ··rZ_³Æð\°vÀ=¥x}~f3,,qXwxËº³ÑØæwRqaÅv¢»FQ@ 
z¯ìýðz÷â¡tízl4Û2¢infcÑTtíÖ¹1Øê
Äb%ËîÊ\Û~ÄÞ½Õ|kÿ    Õ¬O¥iáãFãhïþµöÁPãn0½1æ¾x+Jðí¼?¤haË<÷¤sÕYÔ¼S¦iºÙÞÝE?Ý,@Í;qkS=ÌgZ¼V^K¯Ïs¶ B:ñÏÃvºO5§©=B(ïØB¡<©r1R¸Á-ýÝw99¯=Ònno_jq[ý¯æù+òáN   n+Èv¯~øÕýÅô²­   ÝFèÓ^¥Â§yhþ^"²v0ÎHíÜ?
ü»3¥*x®úµð®&5²êRÖ)¯ÇOºÆA¶ÈÌbkñMø|K¬+Â¬Ç S]¶©ÃÇÈ¼ûÆÑtÃ"¸Ë<ô>`Çò®zæjçÑâªòRroÐãí4­kPÔ
Á³I§q]özôJõßèí Is²{oc½«,KC;o³c Éí_C|ðV4;Ñ¥Ùë«3%ÅÈDÒîv`ñ Õ¨ü=i|i6©å­-VÝ¹ö\c Pî|¼ãm{$ªRåïo»øä³xËu¢÷w»z\ò¿iÉáÝF¶\Ç4òX*äÙ_ëÕÏáVuhítZ¿¶Gma,YîLÆÅ¸ã$£íôÏ­Ç"µ«Ç¥Á%À,òIµô !OÔVt9.5÷ðð.-®ÎrÀ
Æ×
(e$eHòPã<ÈµÁõ7ìçµ/ÂæÑÇ§Z¾þv¸ïéÒiþ´ç
:ÚçÕöàÏ?|ûâÈîZ½¸,¬­s+)ÎrF*ï+é_Ã ø^Y¤Ë1FXöQIÀäWÏ*Ö"¹Òí#Ô4µÛ MdþR´c¦UyêO5îa#ï6|æ.\ÑI½ÙÎ   ý+&kÛØm­âw/ Ú2Xú~·óÛo²(OÊeæ©¥Xø[yywñ&ËN´=¯äÊíµ@^¹ÉèÜW\ÛQm#bä®ÏÔÔ?Ü99Æ*jãüâñö¢lâL`7nuP¬¾Z¬$w5×ÃÊÜ'£F Ý]I#Uo±Äov@[×aPsQÏpÜÕyº|È¯V¥9jàÖn©}ªíàîÏãZtçCF¸QEQEQQJûA÷ºóM+-fjú¯Øm¦¹[w+õ¤2¯lðX{. ÌñWmtË"±KûóùtÎ7·l«Õ=Êø<wq«Â4û ÐX§fÿiñ1êIïYT¨©è÷;0¸9×wè{
¯ÄL^æâ)¶ù_fyX,0\×E¦ë:F¥#Åa©ÙÜËúÈâYÓýå#ñ¯5jÏHÏwq°õ
ÌkÏüCñ_Ô?ÑíîäÑXFù5Ç<o&è÷ðü3,R½6×ØýàÐ+à/üzøáæE]r{øCh¯OáËe}ö/þÖ:tÂ;xzkgÛº°mÈXùäÇ* wÜÇÚ´§¥=§.+1øuueåþ[ûxjWüHÓô¿íÚ%ZàØ:<×Îëÿµg|?ãÛjÞf(ì)n<¢C¹á9ã^A_Ô|#ËýQþ^ý?®çÈW¡QÆJÌ:ÑEôfA^Áðgà'þ%hkvf%òâkf2àá°ä{^?_Q~Â^1»·Õõ/KÒqö¨?êßÃèF?*ùî)ÅãpymJø&ãgª¾w4¦©þÉ9Q¶ÃSÓ/ s,ìÆ1ÏLrM}QðcÀ6_|k [àfK«\y²§è:¥vRKcç`)ÊCøVoÅYmB412\©ßEk¿3®4ãt-yÿ¼m¯xÞþçj¥¹ÿV.:×~ù
pF}ë.dpìäIÅxø,EL<ùé»2¥%fyÿÄÛít(xHØC"Ä£²ï?Óó¯Ô^§å)gæ
ÌþYéÓä¡íÏjî~0øÜjºÛØÙ²­¥²ìÁûÀ»`=A
x£«<ºÌñÉø@ØþÏ?5ñÙ¥uÄËËCö>ÀVÃ`!)éÌïo+Ë÷]üÆ}s^4=r¶Òy0:9ÔíÔ1áÎ9ç<àcÇuxóG#eK¹æÚrÑ¦2l#þù"º¬V=3Ë*®ÛÃ9ºÓsé#ªâß¸´~gÔ¿$þ'ºUº¸È;\F7©ÇpÙ{VýÊ+^9û;øÞ;   ü.î´÷6ÊXñHå9;dfÎxûôÿëi5Î£1ÌpDÒ6OV © äkéèÕJjHü?1ÁÔÂc*Pé¿øyZxbFn¯?ñþ¦^}ºêb-ìÇ¢.K1($å>6øÙ­Ëks£M§$v÷!|¦b<À¸Þã,À¹<äb¸í3Ç·zì·zÆ¥×ÁÚHKn¬AòJ:ÎÑ¸2e(Ô-Ë®ÒKúó;_·zå¼vÅ,í­Àfh®.Lg
ÄDÞBêÊx+^-âj×ûÝxâ&*é]?<a    bqV\a¼£ÄÌFg)¶IÿA]p²<Ê\ÝÙ^ý¤u0#*³pz×Õ¿±ÃKéiñ_¶ª]t¸¦L_óßïü</Ì Þ1äß³§ÃhµÍføÊ:\D=½£øû=FáÚ?çô¯¦ü]âfÓôùî¡I)!!¡äc^õ8àdôJhiÒo¦§±øH·Ñ<5ec    H@ bºÈÅS±;ds2jæG\×v"£«RS»läJÊÂR0FEs*Ô-´{v¹º*ÏSÖ¶oo:nn×üqÒukHn(ó¤;º¾ÀÎ»r¼4kb!
åêMI8ÆèÌOWæ=:9®åå?z/üO&±³[ºÝ+È>üIÔû\¼å·b)³õ>ï:nU@»@Ç½ûû*½ÞÌgKÚ=dh*Ë«k;g¹»¸Þy%pª£ÜQ}f&m¶×ó!_.1ÇscrT
_&Ý5)K1&cAÕàV;\_Ü`Ér¶ËÁÙl¡ ò¸åO²)÷¢?*&ûÀ;|nbN=³KÈRñ¯ôo
iRjZµÄ6VÊ   ïdò#ÞBò±=¶#×kßµßêmkð×ÃÚÖºÂEU¸¶µ[DßíË bÈOr°ë^ÏâÿøsÅSÃ.½£iúÀs¹·Y
ûr:sÓ¥_±Ó,l`x#8Ô*"®@èCºÃÙÅ]«³å½Oà·Å¯jÛþ.ñ5¶+®#³ê{Ç·ÚÌBå®2ÌÃ67ÇJçà·Ç
;[ÖÏ^êÞLÿ¥µûb8Þ7dãøU=kí"(ÀTÎ$í¬Üé6¬tÇÏZ/ìáöë&¸ñwuÍMùÝgqDtÃ)-Ïé\Ï?fírÅ|Í^´¿1hî¡kv°R¥Ãï´WÔ3_0³¯u8'icAg`ROJÆT)=ÑÝC;ÇÒ~íM;=Oü[á_ø\±Öü?yeã3B è<Ä%3í×7öÉ½Gå_k~lÚTÖÚeÅÝ®>i£ A:x+×ùâ't-^Y_Gðv©¦]â[g·³{ÇæíÇû»N{×-Jt©»6©ô×»ä·ò¯Ðñ±}&0UM>ÆæÆ;èe½´yíÕÁ$auî`ãë]%¿ÂO] i=¥ütÑ´ø!«HBÝëöÉ!þbgýN?våÙÕlª|øJîÊúú­ÌèÅ`±õËR7²ü^¨ÔñÎð«Sð"øáæ§«o0Ú=ü«æ$G#z|vÀlµçÙ¯ö/ö×öußöXìÿlòÉóq»fþ±Î+»o^Ó¡[¿¼òÀÛeÎâ9dFô1¢³õ­íkWÁëà2çYÕ4ÎÛ{¶»~Axæç9ë_¤d~+Ï    EQÆÂUþ.¼½tvÕtÔù¼Gb'ïÑ}/ÈòZú£öðädk'fäÞ¶±¯0ÌqÛ9y?ÃZÉ­Êúþþ©ûµè6_=0§ã=§AÃ¾±-,­,¬÷/ÞlñÀîk£<RËñØ9àð°½m]ÞöÑ²pü·<Ú^ZßòGÒó<NÍ-ÍÌQl#È#kHJÈÿM×ükÀ4ß>UËK»Ñ%ò±"K¶@ÉÚæ¬[|H½$«öxÏóZü®¦qI4:ip2ªn-iýyç?tmZkoM5\»½Ò(QêI<WüQøÁ§E¢ÝQD&}~@?1'¢óòÞ"ø©aËkË´<¤  l©¸ð*¥¸?.sí\n¥­x_W¸%¼m0Îb<6 7$G##=ëNT¹©¦¢úQÃTiâ12NKU?oøMuâÈ¥g¸  -ÖXìNØàÿqY£Vf[m:ÚY%K±AÏÔ×ªMeáÉ3»A°'×ì±ÿ8ùAVÖëc UÂ¼o´O¿/v9O  Új/xÚ¥ºE _-·1 bBs¹IÈ'¥uóÜFÓMUØ0kV¿ÜíoÆ8Ï½c5í¥vvÒp´ìJ^hZÝ©§É¶KveMÈÜÄòîèyQÅzUÿÆDÃ×kpØ]Å$F9- ÌdV*C*Ö¹¯|]ã¨Íôp&¥MÈº¼$   Tã\lq´ÿz½Rý/?²¤¾7{µäYtÖYñÆXJØÿd×Ð`h5NÒGå<YÃ×Å©ÒrÙü¶ÔùcYB´ºòÇNÔ%8îc|ÌîNädÎ+.ÛR[KFBL®w³7s]ÅxÀ¾$]#\³3'üzÈ^9`e¿n8## f¾ø=û2höº¯ÄÛ£qvêth%*"}Ù¤9çî¦0GÞ#ïc
O¯«Z<z3xoÂ¾3ñýñÓü9¤Ýß0ûæ%ÄqõÆ÷8Uèz÷~ÍiáµMGÅÃª]µ&ÝOûL@/ôÀ»«ë½+LÒtÍ>+"ÂÒÂÆ­í¢XãOÀqù£SKo²È÷>ZÄYÙÈ
 u$´M¹+ð´^ð9ì*¦Ð::Vmõ¼Ú2_OòÁk#Ãh¸|¸+,¿ðc9ó:¦½Æð[$þ[C§¯F¸¸MÒ(Ï&8ÏFÆpÏÀ ®
y?<i`
7JDPC'DAÀÊÕÈ»«£Éµ?ÚGâ®ÞÁ§ëra¸8Òáã1ïLö¤øµ)ÌÚÄ
Æ0-£_ý¼kX;µ{Ææw?øñ­xÅ¾4¿[ø~ÿTa'»»+ÒmÁèÏ5^G¢Ú;â^Gw5ëI4|¡Äx@PÔ_ÚâTÒÿÇÁØÿÏ(    ?ù
»Ï?±ÍôëçÄMulN¦^R
)û¡Áõ¯¥¾|.ð¢_øEü5egp£ÉÎ¹n?½|°Ú±5%¼ù²Ô-½¾äx_ÃþÔ)=´m=±½NÞÞÝ#¡ÞÃÝT×¿xNÃÆÐÚ)ñOäÔ§`Åge
¼kÇÌ»öïaâÒºbFry>¦ÏX96îÙwVµðØZÅ2N"S:)UBdÛÌr[Ù©þPsÔûÓP*¦âÕZLw¨PsU$$Ö}æ¡yÜâe(Üªäîª7:&ps\Î©®Å3¼ª£$ÀÂj>k÷6þµmQÉÇ [uéÎüýz # V¡ÌÒ4Û=#Tñ½Osq1F¥ÝªÔzW ~)xVæo*Û_Ó¦HîU¿®^Þj·}â[·½4qb#8)HdáçÁÆâ+ø×â]Þ?hÖË©Þ.mÂ¸=C{x;k)Ti\êÃá½µEN
í¿þ&Cgû«;ý>¸£\ÜËò)Ç!Pd#à¨å²0tüãÍoöø/­¨DÁæyVFàª>¤e@$u&¾o³ðàÙd½A5Ã¹Ù:pª;(­à­G®5õ½´FhvèA>¹é|ØÉjâö?CÀðÅ(B©·»¾¿å§ôÙï¾2ñåÖ­ÙUór@ÉY]"»I/¦¨F»j¯îÍ­Gj¤b  ìB®qÎ2FOa^[«:Ó¼õtp8|/gJ6E­WÄ¯pdLU`kLFWp<¨Èç' <s6©êDÜÌÒªs+nÀèÐ
èôÛ´µH3ìP79Ëç¹õ5lQ:î/Ý6.)HÄ@lbk¦#Ñ@«ÖÚM¬íõ=*¼g)r=«)U·fñ¡ìEqýÄø¥¹+ZhaE¤{NÜ=E&åï
³Gôhå|Wá¹å±m_&d²°Ý£siázcà¯ÎCÛj°ÍFå$G´L:ã?6:§$vã½    ¥AÀ9>ÃüEÐþÕöÆÍBe    Ç±õaØõí^®ª¯aÖ/gÕ3å50òúî]îÍo^k¹Û"êÛÐJÌ®¤~D\4ë­&à_éÊÒY©ß$%¢<üèzãÇPqPxÄªH¶iC.CÛèÇñÝÇ9ã¡Õoce*Ï»}¨:Ø
í'§àÑjX<ÿª5i/ü
2^ÕÑ5û]JÝ#Aö¬dzH=GlÿZ7ÀpOp;W¡ø_ZÔ5øèÍË&òÖh ¸óÚ£êqsÁ5ÑÜx#Åºcë ÒVßHÓ¯!÷tÿhÌ:®ÂÀ½NNÒvòAÇMlfÕJ{>¿à~3ÃâÝêCD×Úíóîm¶âký=VÚ->ÖáíåÔ'hÍÂ6~xÕUn0C0U`r¤×Mû1xoÃ×~5Ô-|M®¯¨Z*Ü[¼r-!\ªÊÊ¿¼,IÈÂäFNDw&ø³©ÉgáòÖÚzÉýNLùqg¢/÷Aö¡ð÷Á'%°¶ñm®§tÓasmsKJá1z©pIaÚ8xSiÅ+çXL%N¬ìßE¢K×¯¥Ï¥¼QâMÂÚY½Õ/m¬mW$Ò@{çÒ¼ïöÐ¥ÔÖÛE¶¸Ô¡f
gUU8ÚÊÌOü¢øÏà£âÍ{¯Kç_ÚâäJ¥öÀs$hªÊvÜ¤dùI9#Ó¾ø·Á÷MªiLñ$+Qlìlå|9Rw.~^ìé]ï¡ó4hÐtÛ½ïÌöøRñW</ãÄÓQCib¶Ef
R]§ï+»æÜÙ8á¯|M©Ï«O$·¤B²+eYXu!½Aæ¹sûEøãÂìV×~ÎÖ [KÌÃ$h88;9íÄ¿´ºø×´]"k[ñf°ÞilÙ¸>[;$?9Æp¦*j¯qÂÕh{ÏÂÝvóS?dwÜAàùÒøÏÅöÖðÿ´¬vÌ»­àà¬îÜÿÀù·x~âíTh70iVQÛ.¡×3nÄ-À$D¹\ä×=mâ?ZÊAxój£9IlüÀ±DGRQ@_+CIK
Sv°½·e?|@üGxe;Âl$à.H$?Ûð·Âê6Ë­ÜYÛ[¡â´ºvY_Ýgû¸'×ì_
þé^H5Q!¼ÔÐ|LCmF¾¸$n<ºÑÚøÃÄ_4§¸º`@
ª2ÎÇ¢¨îÇ Õ;jÄêëËÏþ~Ë
ü4Ðßk0Oâ]Hî×Ìûx#ÙËW¶ØØØé¶qÙXZÁimÛ0F# Q*{¹
ÈTt\±5Ò÷8îìHÎN*2ÔÆ`9¨eVÆJÎ*¼³ÐÕi®;Y÷wÉqRÙJ&ñÕFëQ!×&°µ
X~l
áuï¢Þ?KmNÿmðvcAÁÁb3O¬iÜíõ]x"±2QïóÍKÆÓêWgá»VÕ'V*òÛg¸i0FF1qj;
êÑóüOuæ¡äX@Ä[¨ÇF<{p¤W½uVvv0$ñGh0Tz:Vm¶jbrÖ~R.<Q|Ú¤ÍÈ}£ç=z]u¥½²5P;N7
×±Æ¤³Îm±5fÌHâáÙb ev
ÀË2xÉâ¼Pðä×9IgûMÕlÚüíkHùW=¯L
¢½ûÁÚä÷zß,KÃd7æLT«È1{2×ø¶Á¢y,ìbîi'¼'t¬Ý@Éàã=`uÊùøÚ%¯sì¸c    5)IÃWk~vÌä%õ[×0vùùåývc·Q»Ûç#£³·ÖÚ8!EDE
ª£8vVg·Ò,|Âì>XâeöUÔàI k½ÔõË}}ûÂ/õãÀÍkÆêè´Gèñ¡ñk/ëäûR¶³*û¦¹
ÎÜÀ¹=|VQÔ^Gq|QJdÃl¸bA¿½F'à×!y®­°x´»W2?ßbw1Þ-ó¼uÁøÅW÷]½çp­eQ±}°s]Xlê¾Xÿ_äyYyGkUéåßð¿åÜ÷)u86iÒÆ]ÖôÁyê²_0ßÞÞêïn%¸ÕØAè=@À2
zñÈtø¿ø'ÊËÄ;OÝ¡uþ+?ÉU­É#Vúh»Nç|Çg¨êVû-ýÔ>»%#ùÛ²ñ§mÔ/öÊ£´ª­ÄþµÈ*¯¦vPñ    /âÓ},ÿÈúíI×zþuÞÆ:6
ñ>!Þøü³Ço-×5y>!Ø¸PÉ<DõÈÈrO*ÄSÞ'±GrÊËJ©zÝ~g¨Í¨è  üq[¾ðW¼zÒ®[G-ÝÃ3ÀO°ò3Ícüð^¥ñ&õ/³Ûh·ï®¼¢¦LR-Ã»g½Nz±¬ã²ðç¡°Ó,ÖÞÊÕ8`¶NÉ<³1äI$ä[arôÝê-=âïd½
ÞO¯Eþlðß
~Ìú6<ójúõÕïáÊ[Æ-Ð>d$b=v¡®ÓþÏþ·[¸ôÝ6Ý ?%ÍÎ$  ì%L×E«ÿlêP-ØÒ£aÒ-²Ì2sò)={Õø?OTYRMu&öà¤N7mgÎÜñò;àkÕåZ$¶?>&¬ùå»»¶Íü´ÂÍ?îå[k{»]>Û=Ô±4LO]ÉØÀ+¾=O´Id¶6MÛ|ÀpëÀ'ó«¶6º}v¶±,0F0ª>¹$É$I<rkÎ~3kö:lV2<Z SÐÊòDOàÖ­(-NDÝIYlGã­BÃÃ$ÒZÛ¤H#À$Âª¤;)>èOafu
P£êw`5Ã)þêäÙ9lMyÏÅÿÁ¤ßøzëPfºi@ÈèÙbbDäÒº¿|Hð× tmVíÃ¡Î9SÎ2C   ¬yÎN|Hîµi kG°#ÁÆxO[?Ù²iIº}>Ci)wÍ´Äq¹ã(ävßÔý[YDùÍy_u{-}5s#­Òýh37Ë¹ÕFs6C¸ÔÊzè:tî¬jüuE¿ðÌÒß¼ûp^Ñy¤píSõðÃLÛV¾dG³RýÚ±yYp_w|ìÆ9¯|øsÃÿøzóÄ2¿³»EÈH¥¼Øî,~ð§-ô?jRh~¶xo.#}JhgyB§ò3ª.s$!+ØÞ2QMü¬ß%±YÆÝÝ¹#dYWûòdÎã´ýá    èÞ±1XÀÈwÍ3àÉ3yaÀÀ¬\Kc§Çáß$ÞR¬~TKåYEÐ9\`úÅdÔ<C¼6.5½@HÐF³
dn
;±è£¹VJ',å)ìlø[´Ó-kÚ2TY*¨³@rIWxü^ßxouYd"<¶Àõ,FCJ{áGÊ?¶ouÛßj-}¨G,0ª³¶-·ÈÁãþZàõäèrOsâÙ`\I-Åõ´¾D»[çQ÷O¶áôóÀ¬g>cjt¹}O´îNÒ3×«I(*;1éòU%×\§VMêjÅÚ Él
«~ä¬+»·,ÍY9¨¯u.¡ã\Ç|Cg¦[ËªX*3±à*¨åI<
ÉÕõ»Ëù4ÍxÀó¦àáåi ìW%C¨t­k©jW
}¨íÁ¸c`=V5éûHqb3Y·se·)O½âWÿHi4m8óå+¹g£òÆô,Ø=QniV£YkH(ÁÎÌz³Ë1îNIïK=ú¢â<+T×mí´³*ýM!Ý³ õTuÀªZ¤q©%ÀükË¼[ñKGÒC#Ü¡²g-ùkÌµ¯º¢JÙZÍNÐû£9üéÆÈNËv{æ«âÈbTîZ¹{½fmqd/'H"TUSÔzÇ<;ð÷uÍiâ½×î¥Ù!Ý¶ÕÁé¼¿Cø÷êZ&c*¨Ày8Ìc¹IëÜûÜceÇ+-Ôz¿_òûû|]5a·#E
¨£@ÀV^³8äàäõvø¦h!nõ,v5äT²÷ZIÍÕ[t2õh§½·2Ë*mB0zuÁ<ë\o$ÓôçÚÇºp0%Ì ÿ´ÄÖµ|e­}æÝbùySÏmæ#Ô%y-ýÑëõÿë×v
:Eu83\}%9ÕOø<E¬ÖÙÛ{dK'ôË®ÑZïsKåAû5P,OÅ³<Ê¶aYÕ©ò]äqÀ¦vkB@«ÀäÕY Ë+©qY¶PI/QM÷+OÂ>×|[®Á¢ø{MP¾ü±Ä:ìÄðª;)N|¨i6ì¤I%uDVwcÉ'Ò¾§øû/Ý^­·>"ÂöÖÄ  ÒNDèf?Â?Øúã[ý?gÏü8¶]ñ·Õ|IÂR¹ÔúDöÏ>ç>±­øÒÒìûFv¢Y»*¨åök¥W#¢åódmµe
¼VÐB¢8¢ªÀ
ËÖ5$}ID¦;ge@9p0ç9ÆAÝL¯Î±µHµ]B?´ÞÉ6l­¹`\M ÿmÔü¯sÀ;Ç+^SkâkÑz|=h«=ÍKn>e?4ùE°9cGòI>µÍ)Ù§}nzÖ¥¯FÝåUD°ª$ØWcá¿°Ñ~Õs¢ßîX».#¸,qóm# ³
Æøgà4ø¡Õ|Díq,vîAX[¨,P
yäÕèSÏYØ+Zpi^F&»ñ?ì­É.­ebBE4>?º¤e¿×x³O×þ!ß@t­
ö4Òâõä·L0ìC(8` ú×µø_°ØÈò¢¯~k¶ø±àý*g=sLóáÐ\!aõÍD¬÷fÔïx­NUþ
M«ÆÚæ­3.APÄqÕt#¨o½îkÅ<YðÆÞÖßjvÑË¾Ý¢AsëÜ¨tÜ¬}p:§áuøBât]oF\ñµïþæ­xâgltf½½Õì eOÚ}9É>Â,5§^½7uÔðÍ)¼{ýkc¨xgXûLi¶IdÎ:eå¸Ç8É¬Ëâ½ Á5®¯¶¶ò4p-¤9¶sMC0,3òRA©õ]/Ä¾!ñÅÐÙ[Yé§Ë¼ºmìüð|¥ìG<¸> We¥ü9FC{â¯O:$e¥H¶2X¶Lgö4Uäåú/4[{4¹ñ¦¤kZ´¶ÅÅ¥ºÆd»/6åULpÐ®qÎÒp2k»ø{¢Ýi6é°Á
ÍÌäÜÊ¸h¬Â¾Rc$pÄeUNÍ§¤AÑVML·ÒìX~úh¡Ü]ûÀeO\ÍìÝGÅÞ*Òü1¦­­ª+ÜlÙmi00EQÉÀUò¨êÌeQÏEÔ¯âÝwIð^]Ù¦»¸ùhù®e#ócôvQÇ^ê¯~5MbM÷
I··
ísÆG÷¤Ç»dÀ'1Þ\^j:º¦©8¸½Ü3²ã÷qÑr'«NUX§a¥s+   Îæ°¨3,Q;¼[iÛêM3ÀÞ½»çÅiû4VÓä$àg|J°c°§r´è.üC­-Ê   Ìò¨È?nÛÈàz}ãÞÍ¦ÛÇ¥é°ÚÁÃ1ÑEP0ú
")rz
¾_@a°uK9HÏãZ-K©oäXÑ¶ä×:ú}ÙçËjèmqH«$$k#Äzzn=Üî"BÛeöP;xÔÖäJ¤y§/ÿÄ¶º*®øí±yp¼°lD¤¼ò;Ä+'¡¼lÚÓ\Xé¤¥ZàæKSÒ¹,ø=Jv®z*¨íTu-^(PÉ,ª zæ|câ(t¸Ôe8Ýü±Üûu¯<}ñZñÒ[ÚílI#hÈyûDtì?Z¸SG §8Á^G¬xÿã¦<¶2«²#Ðû·AúñsÆ%ñé­ác÷b$zõ=OZça³¸~D·¯ÊMliö³3,I$¡NIô®êxXA^G,«NnÑ
3Gó8i¥sI5é¾ ðC"\\ª¼ÀåTéê}ÿ/SkÂ»·7Z¼0ìîî¯·¿ÈKÐ|7|âÑÇ©Åx9c*·§KáüÏÔ8s¨àÄâÚu7·HÿÁüºw'ðöY
ð£èÙâ¶ziEÝ´8[f+Ö5B&01*ç=Íx­J*ö>ÚGRÜÊÄ÷
q;HÇñô®kÄ:Ãù°;U«ëÉ#å!yLâ¼óÅ×&RB}xÀ£EÉó3¯^aËÄé\>»MsniÜåä¹zæyKØy÷oþ·õö§¥É\ùø  ¯­Ëè{8s=ÙøçæOtbýØïëÿüÊV>ñ¦8Õ~[K9OûäÖn¢^Ý3*:u<×¨òåKvp:ÖEÄäæupÒÚ¿©¯sý?g-wâÅâ/ ôo#
³^ã´@ô^ÛÈÇ\duQçÿ~øâw£[ùVqo/åSå[¯¹þ&=r}$}ñð·áÿ¾x{û7D^ê\5Ýì ®w'°p>¤³ÞøGámtm6ÚßOµOÝÚÚÛ©i%nøyÛ¹cÔÞ¼ûÆºö»á­OU¾çL°ÒIÖÚLHB©lÉ"¸qA.mZÍ³¶.Ç ë$òåìôûmÀm8lC    ÎvîÃä\FfA«>©ªÏöâ¤\`F¤äªà^õ8«¤ÿghº:E
DPPÂ¼úë^×~"ø¼5á7í%þó6pp
cwó.Ý¶6¼mâ{írö
ÃòÏq'] ü$$
w¾iÞº]ÔR+fäþòÛ¡r    ûÎ@¶X·CðãÀ:?ì³úV¥"m¸½pïÜªv&{sHÍnj·RªONµ¼)òë-Ì'WÝÃõ-ND$°Íygük5ÍñÒ4ûUóìµ#7;`í^¼à'£ñkÄZ§=¶nnõIòÐyßi8ÜÄbsÂ©5à¾×ô
ÜK.|Y6³y!qþ#qX'<c$cYÎ£zQ ­sÚÆ§,kñëªÜ`öýÊA!$¨ ;g®sÆ:æÅmt²ÈvEh]Üã8TPY8+³ñw¼Aâû]2-SÅÑXÉm a§I½62nI  |ÍÛWÞº-Gñµ;´H ¶³¸s¿Qñ{ÖLä(X
¹è»ÀéYÚæÜ¶Õ³×¼  «\XFÛi"îuÝIËüU¤8.YU×9eiáïëú.á«}GKÔ¬AªêV{
µÕ¢nòåEf,
©sË`çÔ<UfÚþ°ëõäDë$vPC-¹êî¹Ga÷ÏZÅøm¤ê¶¨ØxKNmNÞãamNWLFùqå»Â)#w#%[]
!;FæÃ©|5á_ÙirÊ
½¹i®/'¢¨Î   EÎ`r¡^EÔu©R}IVQEj§(èÌxÞùç=GáßÂ7ÂZ½÷f¸¼¾Ôï7,0¶ ps1Zþ#ñ2.´Û+·ÛÍÁîçdküRçAw}Ó¢ºZÓ½ÑÞ0ñ/Øó¤èÊ·:{eö¤*rÈÜí àpHñíQeK©âé®®¦ ÜLF7ÐµN<rNX³öKÓÇ§Ú:E#f$³ÈÄcs±åö¬«ô
,ð:É$V3mA($u¹@É5ÍêWwZìvV*gû¹X×»···sÇ.«yu{|ºm-,§§ *çÜöqÜàã¡Ç}ðçÁ7bi"idr²àÈßNÀv¾¹&4m%vm|4ðÄZV¨ªÎíóË#òÎÇ«ê!À¹®:ª2Î1]Lx°²
Ë´ãçµ*æà)Xîé]
6G+3¹ÿÙ
```

I tried use btoa: window.btoa(res.data) to convert data to Base64 string to pass into .
But It don't work. Might because I convert data is wrong.

I using ReactJS library.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) will help. Look at the `FileReader` part. Are the thumbnails on your Server?

Comment: Yes, thumbnail from server.

Comment: But I can't convert data to Base64  to display.

Comment: Recommend converting binary to base64 on server itself. A sample IMG tag which works is `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA
ANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU
5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />` maybe you could compare where you are missing out.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta,I can't fix on server. :(

Comment: How do you make the call to this API ? I guess you're doing an ajax call to an url, if so, can't you just pass this url as the `src` of your img ?

Comment: Kaiido, response of API has "url for download file binary" and url is a Location key of response header. But I don't know why it auto redirect to url (in location key of header) and return binary data of image.

Answer (score 1):

You could first convert them into base64, assign this value to a variable (let's say 'img_base64_val' in this case) and then send it with some markup to this line

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,img_base64_val">
```

where img_base64_val is our variable from before, of course.

Comment: Can you suggest for me how to convert data above to base64? I have tried many ways but it convert wrong.

Comment: try this `let img_base64_val = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(binaryData)));`

Comment: <img src="data:image/*; base64,77+977+977+977+9ABBKRklGAAEBAAABAAEAAO+/ve+/vQB0RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAEABoBBQABAAAAPgAAABsBBQABAAAARgAAACgBAwABAAAAAgAAAGnvv70EAA.../>

Comment: It can't display.

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this:

```
<img src=`data:image/jpeg;base64,${binary_data}`/>
```

`binary_data` will be the variable that will contain the binary data;

Comment: Should value be binary data?  Or binary data converted to base64 using [btoa()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa). 1) `btoa(results.data)`, I get `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range`.  2) 
 `btoa(encodeURIComponent(results.data))`, displays broken image icon.  3) `URL.createObjectURL(results.data)`, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed`.  4)  Binary data, the page is filled with 'diamond' and random characters.

Comment: I am using this Microsoft Graph API endpoint which _says_ it returns binary data - but maybe that is not true:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#examples